# Script should run by own during server startup

Tags: linux, unix

We are using JON tool to monitor our infrastructure .we set up the threshold for RAM usage(60%,65% of total RAM)using tool GUI.

In case if server(which is in in cloud ) RAM size is increased  we need to manually change the threshold level using GUI .To avoid that I wrote a shell script which uses JON CLI to update the threshold of RAM (based on current RAM size), script is working and no problem in that.

For example, initially if RAM size is 8 gb we set up the threshold (65% from 8gb) based on current size.
Due to some need if they increase the size to 16 GB we need to set up the threshold(65% from 16GB) manually.To avoid that I created  shell script which uses JON CLI. to update threshold value( during maintenance  they shut down the  servers and increase the RAM size as per their need.)

## Problem:

If the server size is increased I need to run the script manually to set the threshold.
Since they are bringing the server to down during size changes , the script need to run by own once they started the server.
So I placed my script in /etc/rc.local file
Recently the team has increased the RAM size and started the server but there is no change in threshold (which means script doesn't run by own).
Thus i ran the script manually to update the threshold

## Expectation:

Script should run by own during server start up.

Even though it is basic thing please guide and help on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can make any executable run at startup using a cron job.  To add a cron job, enter the command `crontab -e`.  This will open the cron table editor.  Now, enter the line `@reboot /path/to/execuable` and save and quit.  Make sure to replace "/path/to/executable" with the path to your script.

More information about cron can be obtained by running `man cron` and `man crontab`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..is cron the only solution??

Comment: @karthikraj Cron is installed automatically and on all systems.  Any other solutions would probably not be this easy.  Try it.